# What properties of DNA and Chromosones do birds have?

Tags: dna, ornithology

What properties of DNA and Chromosones do birds have? How many chromosones do males and females have? Are the nucleotides the same (CGAT)?

There are a lot of different kinds of birds. Maybe the DNA varies a lot among them, so I want to specify: Fowls (gamefowl/landfowl/waterfowl).

Comment: Yes. Birds do have DNA. I don't understand what you mean by the type. If you mean by geometry, I suppose they should be having all 3 A, B, Z- DNA. Chromosome number varies with species. 'Birds' is a class of animals with many many species.. so ya - you can't generalize. Sex determination also varies. Since you ask for the fowl - males are homogametic - ZZ and females are heterogametic with ZW. So in a way, it is opposite to that in humans. I don't understand why you expect birds to be that different

Comment: -1, the most basic search will confirm that birds, and indeed all life above eukaryotes, have genomes encoded by DNA.

Comment: @Michael_A Which is why I asked "what **kind** of DNA"---and specified the properties I'm interested in, instead of asking "do they have DNA at all?".

Comment: Then, what are the 'kinds' of DNA u r looking for?

Comment: @DrZ214, My comment is specific to these **two** questions. `Is it really DNA, or rather RNA, or something else? Are the nucleotides the same (CGAT)?` You have posed 4 questions which confuses the issue. Polisetty's question is a good one, I also don't understand what you mean by `kind` of DNA.

Comment: @Polisetty I specified in the OP: chromosones, nucleotides, and DNA or RNA. Those 3 things are what I mean by "kind".

Comment: Then everthing is the same. Just chromosome number varies

Comment: @DrZ214 Not to be offensive, but knowledge about DNA is probably one of the most basic things when it comes to biology. Exactly because it is basic, it is also easy to find on the internet, e.g. Wikipedia page on DNA. DNA is not RNA. DNA and RNA are made up of nucleotides. Chromosomes are condensed DNA packaged by histones and scaffolding proteins. You have contradicted your own question by listing those "kinds" of DNA. DNA has probably only two qualifiers: linear/circular, single-stranded/double-stranded.

Comment: @LiuTianyi I made some edits.

Answer (score 3):

The class "Aves" fall under the kingdom Animalia. Therefore, they are multicellular eukaryotic organisms. Being eukaryotes, their genetic information is encoded in linear double stranded DNA.

What is their chromosome number? Fowls (gallus Domesticus) have approximately [36](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jmor.1050430107/abstract). It varies from bird species to bird species as much as it does from humans (46) to gorrilas (48). Chickens have 78, and so on.

The genetic code is [**universal**](https://www.msi.umn.edu/~lifang/misc/genetic_code.html). It is used by virtually all known organisms, save some very specific outliers.